# self.ids.clayout.ids give empty dictionary even though it contains widgets

Tags: python, dictionary, kivy

In this code, `self.ids` returns me the dictionary with child elements which include `id: clayout`. In the `__init__()`, I have added five buttons to `BoxLayout(id:clayout)` . But when I get `self.ids.clayout.ids` it gives me empty dictionary. Small mistake which I couldn't find. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox

import xlrd
import openpyxl
Mess = {
            'mess1': 'RR - SI',
            'mess2': 'VTH - SI',
            'mess3': 'SK - SI',
            'mess4': 'CV - SI',
            'mess5': 'CR - NI',
            'mess6': 'AD - NI',
            'mess7': 'MD - NI',
            'mess8': 'MDJ - NI',
            'mess9': 'FC - HM'  
}
Builder.load_string('''
<ChoiceLayout>
    orientation:'vertical'
    Label:
        text: "Mess Registration for Jul-Nov 2016"
        size_hint: (None,None)
        font_size:'48dp'
        size_hint_y:1
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
    BoxLayout:
        id: blayout
        orientation:'horizontal'
        size_hint_y:2
        Label:
            text: 'NAME : {}'.format('R GOKULAN')
            id: name
            size_hint: (1,None)
            font_size:'36dp'
            pos_hint: {'left': 1}
        Label:
            text: 'ROLL NUMBER : {}'.format('CS15B033')  #Put some variable for Roll number here as rnum
            id: rollno
            size_hint: (1.25,None)
            font_size:'36dp'
            pos_hint: {'right': 1}
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 1
        id: clayout
    Button:
        id: submit
        text: 'Submit'
        size_hint: (None,None)
        height: "36px"
        width: '50px'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        on_press: root.register_mess()

    ''')



class ChoiceLayout(BoxLayout):
    choices = []
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ChoiceLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.drop_down1 = CustomDropDown()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
        dropdown1 = DropDown()
        for mess,mname in Mess.iteritems():
            btn = Button(text=mname , size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown1.select(btn.text))
            dropdown1.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton1 = Button(text='Choice 1', size_hint=(1, 1), id='btn1')
        mainbutton1.bind(on_release=dropdown1.open)
        dropdown1.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton1, 'text', x))
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
        dropdown2 = DropDown()
        for mess,mname in Mess.iteritems():
            btn = Button(text=mname , size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown2.select(btn.text))
            dropdown2.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton2 = Button(text='Choice 2', size_hint=(1, 1), id='btn2')
        mainbutton2.bind(on_release=dropdown2.open)
        dropdown2.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton2, 'text', x))
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
        dropdown3 = DropDown()
        for mess,mname in Mess.iteritems():
            btn = Button(text=mname , size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown3.select(btn.text))
            dropdown3.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton3 = Button(text='Choice 3', size_hint=(1, 1), id='btn3')
        mainbutton3.bind(on_release=dropdown3.open)
        dropdown3.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton3, 'text', x))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        dropdown4 = DropDown()
        for mess,mname in Mess.iteritems():
            btn = Button(text=mname , size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown4.select(btn.text))
            dropdown4.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton4 = Button(text='Choice 4', size_hint=(1, 1), id='btn4')
        mainbutton4.bind(on_release=dropdown4.open)
        dropdown4.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton4, 'text', x))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        dropdown5 = DropDown()
        for mess,mname in Mess.iteritems():
            btn = Button(text=mname , size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown5.select(btn.text))
            dropdown5.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton5 = Button(text='Choice 5', size_hint=(1, 1),id='btn5')
        mainbutton5.bind(on_release=dropdown5.open)
        dropdown5.bind(on_select= lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton5, 'text', x))
        self.ids.clayout.add_widget(mainbutton1)
        self.ids.clayout.add_widget(mainbutton2)
        self.ids.clayout.add_widget(mainbutton3)
        self.ids.clayout.add_widget(mainbutton4)
        self.ids.clayout.add_widget(mainbutton5)

    def register_mess(self):
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('database.xlsx')
        sheet1 = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
        i=2
        # while(sheet1['A'+str(i)] != None):
        #if str(sheet1['A'+str(i)]) == 'cs15b033':
        # sheet1['B'+str(i)] = Mess.keys()[Mess.values().index(self.ids.btn1.text)]
        # sheet1['C'+str(i)] = Mess.keys()[Mess.values().index(self.ids.btn2.text)]
        # sheet1['D'+str(i)] = Mess.keys()[Mess.values().index(self.ids.btn3.text)]
        # sheet1['E'+str(i)] = Mess.keys()[Mess.values().index(self.ids.btn4.text)]
        # sheet1['F'+str(i)] = Mess.keys()[Mess.values().index(self.ids.btn5.text)]
        print self.ids.clayout.ids
        i += 1
        workbook.save('database.xlsx')
        print 'success'


class RegisterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChoiceLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RegisterApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ids` dictionary is only populated by the kv lang parser. You have to keep track of dynamically created widgets yourself. You could store widgets in a `ListProperty`, for example.